# Why definition of categorical product works for $C'=$(Int, Int, Bool) and $C=($Int, Bool$)$?

Tags: category-theory

[In milewski-ctfp](https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf/blob/5fba3fe9c23b1fcbe00f11577e97aaf1ce6d0b36/src/content/1.5/Products%20and%20Coproducts.tex#L386)

is said that one can convert pseudo-product `C' = (Int, Int, Bool)` to product `C = (Int, Bool)` using function `m` that is uniquely determined as

`m (x, _, b) = (x, b)`

But there are two ways to define `m`

```
m (x, _, b) = (x, b)
m (_, x, b) = (x, b)
```

They are not equal, then `m` is not unique, then `(int, bool)` is not a product

Can you point where I'm wrong?

---

P.S. this is duplicate of issue https://github.com/hmemcpy/milewski-ctfp-pdf/issues/127

---

Update

[image part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/718KQ.jpg)

[image part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0eUc.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't think you are using standard terminology; your question would be better if you wrote it in the language category theorists usually use, or at least provide sufficient definition so that people can know what you mean by the words and operations you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Int, Bool)` together with `p :: (Int, Bool) -> Int` and `q :: (Int, Bool) -> Bool` given by the two projections is indeed a product of `Int` and `Bool`.

Recall that a product of two objects `a` and `b` is given by an object `c` together with two functions `p :: c -> a`, `q :: c -> b` such that for any other object `c'` and functions `p' :: c' -> a`, `q' :: c' -> b` there is a unique function `m :: c' -> c` **such that `p' = p . m`, `q' = q . m`**.

This last bit is important: there can be many functions `m' :: c' -> c`, but only one of them shall satisfy both `p' = p . m'` and `q' = q . m'`.

Let `c' = (Int, Int, Bool)` and `p' :: (Int, Int, Bool) -> Int`, `q' :: (Int, Int, Bool) -> Bool` with `p' (x, _, _) = x` and `q' (_, _, b) = b`.

If you define `m :: c' -> c` by `m (_, x, b) = (x, b)`, then you have that `p' (x, y, b) = x` but `p (m (x, y, b)) = p (y, b) = y`, and so `p' = p . m` does not hold.

Therefore, it is true that there are two ways to define `m :: c' -> c` – actually, there are even more! We could also have `m (x, _, _) = (x, True)`, or `m (_, _, b) = (0, b)`, ... but of all these functions there is **only one that satisfies `p' = p . m`, `q' = q . m`**. This is what makes `(Int, Bool)` together with `p :: (Int, Bool) -> Int` and `q :: (Int, Bool) -> Bool` a product of `Int` and `Bool`.

Comment: I still don't understand, I added images to my question

Comment: I think I understand now - though possible implementations of **graphs** are many, in each of them there only one possible implementation of `m`

Comment: You are saying that `m (_, x, b) = (x, b)` will not work with `p' (x, y, b) = x` - of course it will not, but it will work with `p' (x, y, b) = y`, this is second possible implementation of graph, and them are many, and each of them have unique `m`. But `(Int, Int, Bool)` will not have unique `m`, that's why its not a product

Comment: Yes. To be more precise, you shouldn't say "`(Int, Int, Bool)` will not have a unique `m`". You should say "`(Int, Int, Bool)` together with `p' :: (Int, Int, Bool) -> Int` and `q' :: (Int, Int, Bool) -> Bool` defined by `p' (x, _, _) = x` and `q' (_, _, b) = b` is not a product of `Int` and `Bool` because it's not true that for any `c''` together with `p'' :: c'' -> Int` and `q'' :: c'' -> Bool` there exists a unique `m :: c'' -> (Int, Int, Bool)` such that `p'' = p' . m` and `q'' = q' . m`".

Answer (score 1):

If I interprete the notation correctly, we are given

$$\begin{align}p\colon \text{(Int, Int, Bool)}&\to \text{Int}\\(x,y,z)&\mapsto x\\
q\colon \text{(Int, Int, Bool)}&\to \text{Bool}\\(x,y,b)&\mapsto b\end{align}$$
and are looking for $m\colon\text{(Int, Int, Bool)}\to\text{(Int,  Bool)}    $ such that $\text{fst}\circ m=p$ and $\text{snd}\circ m=q$.
If we want to compute $m(x,y,z)$, the result will certainly be of the form $(u,v)$ with $u\in\text{Int}$ and $v\in\text{Bool}$. From $$u=\text{fst}(u,v)=\text{fst}(m(x,y,z))=(\text{fst}\circ m)(x,y,z)=p(x,y,z)=x$$
$$v=\text{snd}(u,v)=\text{snd}(m(x,y,z))=(\text{snd}\circ m)(x,y,z)=q(x,y,z)=z$$
we conclude that $m(x,y,z)=(u,v)=(x,z)$, as stated in the text.

---

*Remark:* It seems you instead skimmed over a different bug in the text:

```
For instance, there is a
Boolean-valued function (a predicate) defined for every type:

\begin{Verbatim}
yes :: a -> Bool
yes _ = True
\end{Verbatim}
But \code{Bool} is not a terminal object. There is at least one more
\code{Bool}-valued function from every type:

\begin{Verbatim}
no :: a -> Bool
no _ = False
\end{Verbatim}
```

The point is that for the second function is in general *not* different from the first function (and so not "one more"). For (exhaustive) example, if `a` happens to be `Void`, both `yes` and `no` are the same, `absurd`.

Comment: Good point! Should be "every type, except `Void`".